# Converting to const in C++

Tags: c++, macos, constants

C++, OS X, Carbon API.

I need to pass in a `const FSSpec` to a method `FSpOpenDF`

I have as follows:

```
const FSSpec fsSpec = fFileSpec.GetFSSpec();/* is declared as FSSpec GetFSSpec() const; */

err = ::FSpOpenDF(fsSpec, 1, &refNumber);
```

But I get an error that is:

```
error: cannot convert 'const FSSpec' to 'const FSSpec*' for argument '1' to 'OSErr FSpOpenDF(const FSSpec*, SInt8, short int*)'
```

I have tried defining as:

```
const FSSpec*  fsSpec = fFileSpec.GetFSSpec();
```

and that doesn't help. So Obviously I am confused.

Can anyone explain the concept I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
FSSpec fsSpec = fFileSpec.GetFSSpec();
err = ::FSpOpenDF(&fsSpec, 1, &refNumber);
```

You seem to understand the need to take the address of an object when calling a function wanting a pointer, as you do it with `refNumber`; the same merely needs to be done with the `fsSpec` object since a `const FSSpec*` is expected.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the `FSpOpenDF` function want an FSSpec pointer. Try:

`err = ::FSpOpenDF(&fsSpec, 1, &refNumber);`